# Find the right words to describe the composition of a discount

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I need to describe discounts, splitting their components in 3 parameters and I would like to understand which are the best words I can use.

Examples:

- **New client** discount, **10** **euro**
- **Personal** discount, **15** **%**
- **Unconditional** discount, **5** **dollars**

The components are so grouped

- 5, 15, 10 = can I call this "value"?
- fixed *(euro, dollars)*, percent = can I call this "type"?
- new client, personal, unconditional = should I use "kind" for this?

*Type*, *kind* and *sort of* seems to me quite the same... and I don't know if they are good for my case.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If these are going to be listed in columns and you are looking for headings, then going by your examples I would suggest value or amount, type, and reason. I would prefer amount to value because in a commercial context value suggests to me the actual currency figure.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please make sure to flesh out your answers as much as possible and cite any relevant sources. This will help you earn reputation.

Answer (score 0):

- I would call each value an **Amount**.
- **Kind** or **Category** might be good for New Client, Unconditional, etc.
- **Type** is probably a good word for fixed vs. percentage.

So you might have something like this:

**TYPES OF DISCOUNTS**

| **Category** | **Type** | **Amount** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New Client | Fixed | 10 euros |
| Personal | Percentage | 15% |
| Unconditional | Fixed | 5 euros |

Instead of *Fixed*, you can also say **Flat** or **Flat Rate**.